# How to help Windows or Windows Applications handle Composite Joysticks correctly?

Tags: windows, usb, composite, joystick

The context for this question is primarily Windows 7, though I've tried it on 10 as well.

I've built a 4-player composite joystick using the Arduino Mega 2560. It is a USB device composed of 4 HID Joystick interface, each with its own endpoint. Each joystick accompanied with its buttons shows up correctly in Device Manager as a separate HID interface. They are identified by a VID/PID/MI_# triplet correctly, with MI_# being the interface index (MI_0, MI_1, etc). Calibration also sees each interface as separate, with inputs correctly corresponding to each controller in their enumerated order (ie: the first one receives inputs from only the joystick at index 0). When I dump the Descriptors, they also look correct.

There are two issues:

#### 1) Naming

Windows only reads the interface string from the first interface. According to the Descriptor dump, each interface should have its own string, going from "Player 1" to "Player 4". Windows 7 sees them all as "Player 1". Inspecting regedit, this may because Windows 7 only has one OEM Name per joystick device, and so only gets the one for the first interface. Am I stuck with this behaviour, unless I somehow get a resolution from Microsoft?

For some reason, Windows 10 calls them all "Arduino Joystick". I'm not sure if because I'm using the same Test VID/PID combo I got from an Arduino Joystick tutorial and Windows is just picking up the name that someone else has used for their device, or if it is concatenating my Manufacturer String with the interface type "Joystick". I'm not sure why it would do the latter, but if it's the former I'd prefer to block that look-up somehow.

I'd like to resolve both, but practically speaking I'm using Windows 7 mostly.

#### 2) Mixed Inputs

I've seen this behaviour only with some applications, but unfortunately one of them is Steam, and the others may be due to Unity. It manifests differently, so I'm lead to believe it's due to there being no standard way for dealing with composite joysticks.

On Steam, in Big Picture mode when I try to add/test a controller, while it detects all 4 controllers (all as Player 4, I might add), it only accepts the inputs from Joy4 no matter which of the controllers I choose. After saving the config however, all the joysticks have the same mappings applied. This is actually good, as I can use any controller to navigate Big Picture mode, but I'm concerned it's symptomatic of other problems which I might be seeing in other applications.

In "Race the Sun", when manually configuring joystick controls (it says Player 4 is detected), it will interpret inputs from a single joystick as coming from multiple joysticks. Usually, two of the four directional inputs come from Joy1, while the two other come from another Joystick other than the one being used. Eg: if I'm configuring Joy2, it'll register inputs from Joy1 and say Joy3.

In "Overcooked", it allows a single joystick to register as 4 different players. Normally you'd hit a particular button on the controller you want to use to register as a player, but in my case if you hit that button on joy1 4 times, then 4 players will be registered. If you start the game like this, you end-up controlling all 4 characters simultaneously with one joystick. Interesting, but not the intended usage, I'm sure.

Both "Race the Sun" and "Overcooked" are developed using Unity, and I understand that Unity's joystick management is rather lacking. Overcooked at least is designed to handle multiple players though (it's a couch co-op game), so this probably has more to do with the composite nature of my controllers.

I should note that other applications have no problems differentiating between the joysticks. Even xbox360ce sees them as separate, and the emulation works on several Steam games, single and multiplayer. Overcooked is still getting the joysticks crossed even though I'm using xbox360ce with it.

The question I'm bringing to Stack Overflow is what could I do to improve how applications handle my joysticks? Right now I'm using the generic Windows game controller driver. Theoretically this should have been enough, but issue #1 shows that composite joysticks may not be an expected use case. Would driver development even have a hope of resolving the issue with the applications I mentioned above, as I don't see how the device would differ significantly in its identification. I'm hoping someone more experienced with coding for USB devices can offer some insight.

For what it's worth, my Arduino sketch and firmware can be found [here](https://github.com/lancerdl/MultiplayerArduinoUSBJoystick).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for "Race the Sun" and "Overcooked".

"Race the Sun" may have expected my joystick to provide axis ranges from 0 to a certain maximum (eg: 32767). I had the firmware set up going from -255 to +255. While other applications handle this fine, "Race the Sun" may expect the more common 0-X behaviour (this is the range that a Logitech joystick of mine provides). After changing this, I was able to configure and play it correctly. I've also updated my GitHub project; the link is in the original question.

The problem with "Overcooked" was actually caused by a badly configured or corrupted xbox360ce installation. Somewhere in tinkering with the emulator I must have screwed something up, as I messed up games that were previously working. I solved it by wiping all its files, including the content in ProgramData/X360CE, and re-downloading everything and redoing the controllers. Now all my games seem to be behaving correctly.

This still leaves the problem with Steam. For some reason Steam doesn't remember my joystick configuration from reboot to reboot. For the time-being I've decided just to put up with the default joystick behaviour, but would like to sort this one out eventually, too.